How to trigger a Firebase Cloud Function for a specific DB instance?
I have 2 DB in the same project, and I need to trigger "onDocumentCreated" for a specific DB.
The problem is that this function has only 2 parameters :

document — The Firestore document path to trigger on.
handler — Event handler which is run every time a Firestore create occurs.

So I can not specify the DB instance for the document path.
Here is how I initialize my app :
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const dbApplication = getFirestore(app, "application");
const dbUser = getFirestore(app, "user");


There is a version of each trigger (v2 only) that accepts a firestore database instance ID as part of a DocumentOptions configuration object passed to the trigger definition function.  For example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.md#firestoreondocumentupdated_2
